# Tableview swipe delete method is not being called

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a weird problem. I have a tableviewcontroller subclass viewcontroller.

```
@interface TestViewController : UITableViewController<UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate>
@end
```

When I swipe on a table cell

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

is fired with a delete button on the right of the cell, and when i click delete, the cell does go away, but the method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

is never called... I want to do some custom code when delete is called, but I can't seem to do so... what am i missing?

Comment: Have you set the tableview's delegate? I notice that your TestViewController doesn't conform to UITableViewDataSource or UITableViewDelegate.

Comment: in my storyboard, i hooked up the tableview's delegate to TestViewController, i'm setting the datasource from Coredata...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cell goes away, but your code did not make it go away, then some other class is acting as the data source and is implementing `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` and is making the cell go away - because, do you see, even if the button appears, the cell will not go away by itself.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for, I knew it was something silly.